# How to find out capacity for network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems, linux-networking

I could get the capacity for the network interface by lshw, but which file in sysfs is this information stored(i.e. which file in /sys/class/net/eth0/device/ directory)?

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:97:0e:b4:5c:6a
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f253b000-f253bfff ioport:6080(size=32)


$ ls /sys/class/net/eth0/device/
broken_parity_status      d3cold_allowed  enable         local_cpus  net        remove    resource0  subsystem_device
class                     device          firmware_node  modalias    numa_node  rescan    resource1  subsystem_vendor
config                    dma_mask_bits   irq            msi_bus     power      reset     resource2  uevent
consistent_dma_mask_bits  driver          local_cpulist  msi_irqs    ptp        resource  subsystem  vendor
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place.

Look at `/sys/class/net/<device>/speed`.

Comment: `cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/speed: Invalid argument`, how to get the content?

Comment: You didn't ask about _wireless_ interfaces. These have no fixed link speed anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have also found out that. So what's the unit for this file:
`sudo cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed` gives 100 while lshw shows `capacity: 1Gbit/s size: 100Mbit/s`.(I wonder where size comes from. sorry this might be another question).

Comment: 100 means it's actually running at 100Mbit/sec.

Comment: How could I know the max capacity(not which speed it is now) for this interface?

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872058/get-link-speed-programmatically

Answer (score 4):

You can check the interface capacity in following ways.

1. `dmesg | grep eth0`
2. `mii-tool -v eth0`
3. `ethtool eth0`

**Note:** Change the device name according to yours.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you could find this out using a tool such as strace:

```
sudo  strace -e trace=file -f -s128  lshw -class network
```

Comment: You are so nice to tell me how to trace files opened by programs. Thanks.